# NSLocalizedString doesn’t work in Swift

Tags: swift, localization

I have this problem with the interface localized strings:

```
var friendsNumber = 3
var firstString = NSLocalizedString("I have 3 friends.", comment: "") // the translation works good

var secondString = NSLocalizedString("I have \(friendsNumber) friends.", comment: "") // the translation doesn’t work
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Ok, it’s works with %d for te variables of type Int but for thats of type Double, doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need in the 2nd case is a format string.

```
var messageFormat = NSLocalizedString("I have %d friends.", comment: "")
var message = String(format: messageFormat, friendsNumber)
```

Then in the strings file you end up with:

English:

```
"I have %d friends" = "I have %d friends";
```

Spanish:

```
"I have %d friends" = "Tengo %d amigos";
```

etc.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I mean "I have \\(friendsNumber) friends." should work the OP forgets the backsplash see edit orginal photo in my answer